# R: Assign repeated sequence of numbers starting from 1 to multiple repeated values with random starts

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I feel there must be a function for this but can't figure out how to phrase my problem correctly in order to find it.

Here is a sample from a datafile I'm working with:
*(sorry for using `dput` I couldn't figure out how to generate an example)*

```
df<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18571, 18578, 18581, 18582, 
                                      18574, 18577, 18582, 18566, 18569, 18570, 18572, 18574, 18575, 
                                      18576, 18579, 18580, 18572, 18575, 18569, 18566, 18567, 18574, 
                                      18579, 18563, 18565, 18569, 18570, 18574, 18579, 18581, 18568, 
                                      18573, 18574, 18577, 18578, 18579, 18580, 18558, 18564, 18565, 
                                      18580, 18573, 18578, 18580, 18565, 18577, 18561, 18565, 18566, 
                                      18567, 18572, 18574, 18580, 18562, 18580, 18568, 18578, 18571, 
                                      18572, 18581, 18583, 18567, 18572, 18576, 18581, 18582, 18574, 
                                      18568, 18570, 18573, 18578, 18582, 18580, 18582, 18571, 18573, 
                                      18575, 18580, 18578, 18579, 18580, 18569, 18571, 18572, 18581, 
                                      18582, 18583, 18567, 18571, 18573, 18579, 18580, 18581, 18569, 
                                      18573, 18582, 18559, 18562, 18574, 18578, 18580, 18559, 18561, 
                                      18565, 18566, 18572, 18576, 18577, 18579, 18583, 18561, 18566, 
                                      18572, 18575, 18561, 18564, 18563, 18567, 18579, 18581, 18568, 
                                      18569, 18573, 18577, 18562, 18564, 18568, 18575, 18577, 18569, 
                                      18571, 18580, 18578, 18574, 18575, 18579, 18580, 18562, 18567, 
                                      18570, 18574, 18576, 18566, 18568, 18570, 18571, 18572, 18573, 
                                      18574, 18569, 18574, 18575, 18564, 18569, 18571, 18576, 18580, 
                                      18576, 18569, 18572, 18573, 18567, 18562, 18568, 18575, 18576, 
                                      18578, 18561, 18562, 18566, 18561, 18568, 18579, 18580, 18583, 
                                      18578, 18581, 18582, 18579, 18580, 18581, 18582, 18583, 18569, 
                                      18570, 18572, 18573, 18575, 18576, 18564, 18568, 18569, 18570, 
                                      18572, 18569, 18575, 18576, 18578, 18581, 18574), class = "Date"), 
                   id = c(11368, 13543, 13543, 13543, 13798, 13798, 13798, 22657, 
                          22657, 22657, 22657, 22657, 22657, 22657, 22657, 22657, 28666, 
                          28666, 28738, 29392, 29392, 29392, 29392, 29476, 29476, 29476, 
                          29476, 29476, 29476, 29476, 29488, 29488, 29488, 29488, 29488, 
                          29488, 29488, 29503, 29524, 29524, 29524, 31513, 31513, 31513, 
                          33037, 33037, 37234, 37234, 37999, 37999, 37999, 41575, 45730, 
                          45757, 45757, 45760, 45760, 46957, 46957, 46957, 46957, 50458, 
                          50458, 50458, 50458, 50458, 50479, 50509, 50509, 50575, 50575, 
                          51016, 52621, 52621, 52669, 52669, 52669, 52669, 53971, 53971, 
                          53971, 54070, 54070, 54070, 54070, 54070, 54070, 54133, 54133, 
                          54133, 54133, 54133, 54133, 54223, 54223, 54223, 54415, 54415, 
                          54415, 54415, 54415, 54511, 54511, 54511, 54511, 54511, 54511, 
                          54511, 54511, 54511, 54523, 54523, 54523, 54523, 54613, 54613, 
                          54730, 54730, 54844, 54844, 55483, 55483, 55483, 55483, 55549, 
                          55549, 55549, 55549, 55549, 55654, 55654, 55654, 55696, 55699, 
                          55699, 55699, 55699, 55975, 56074, 56074, 56074, 56074, 56086, 
                          56086, 56086, 56086, 56086, 56086, 56086, 56194, 56194, 56194, 
                          56839, 56839, 56839, 56839, 56839, 56866, 56974, 56974, 56974, 
                          57103, 58696, 58696, 58696, 58696, 58696, 58753, 58753, 58753, 
                          59044, 59044, 60988, 60988, 60988, 112240, 112240, 112240, 
                          172655, 172655, 293198, 293198, 293198, 621539, 621539, 621539, 
                          621539, 621539, 621539, 696281, 696281, 696281, 696281, 696281, 
                          729597, 729597, 742241, 742241, 742241, NA), week = c(928, 
                                                                                1040, 1041, 1041, 506, 506, 506, 356, 356, 357, 357, 357, 
                                                                                357, 357, 358, 358, 140, 140, 701, 652, 652, 653, 653, 363, 
                                                                                363, 363, 364, 364, 365, 365, 659, 659, 659, 660, 660, 660, 
                                                                                660, 76, 258, 258, 259, 977, 977, 977, 406, 408, 272, 272, 
                                                                                435, 435, 436, 399, 1201, 237, 239, 645, 646, 336, 336, 337, 
                                                                                338, 638, 638, 639, 639, 640, 949, 708, 708, 963, 963, 935, 
                                                                                901, 901, 893, 893, 893, 894, 984, 984, 984, 694, 694, 694, 
                                                                                696, 696, 696, 307, 308, 308, 308, 308, 308, 751, 751, 752, 
                                                                                153, 153, 154, 155, 155, 118, 118, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 
                                                                                120, 121, 251, 251, 252, 253, 167, 167, 216, 217, 1075, 1075, 
                                                                                91, 91, 92, 92, 188, 188, 189, 189, 190, 484, 484, 485, 879, 
                                                                                744, 744, 744, 744, 300, 449, 449, 450, 450, 540, 540, 540, 
                                                                                540, 540, 541, 541, 844, 844, 844, 279, 280, 280, 281, 281, 
                                                                                378, 413, 413, 413, 687, 265, 265, 266, 267, 267, 195, 195, 
                                                                                195, 286, 286, 1145, 1145, 1145, 1152, 1152, 1152, 1173, 
                                                                                1173, 1243, 1243, 1243, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 442, 442, 
                                                                                442, 442, 442, 800, 800, 1061, 1061, 1061, 829)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                      -200L))
```

What I'd like to do, is for any unique `id` recode the `week` column to `newcolumn` so that is stars from `1`, for example:

```
         date     id week newcolumn
1   2020-11-05  11368  928 1
2   2020-11-12  13543 1040 1
3   2020-11-15  13543 1041 2
4   2020-11-16  13543 1041 2
5   2020-11-08  13798  506 1
6   2020-11-11  13798  506 1
7   2020-11-16  13798  506 1
8   2020-10-31  22657  356 1
9   2020-11-03  22657  356 1
10  2020-11-04  22657  357 2
11  2020-11-06  22657  357 2
12  2020-11-08  22657  357 2
13  2020-11-09  22657  357 2
14  2020-11-10  22657  357 2
15  2020-11-13  22657  358 3
16  2020-11-14  22657  358 3
17  2020-11-06  28666  140 1
18  2020-11-09  28666  140 1
19  2020-11-03  28738  701 1
20  2020-10-31  29392  652 1
21  2020-11-01  29392  652 1
22  2020-11-08  29392  653 2
23  2020-11-13  29392  653 2
24  2020-10-28  29476  363 1
25  2020-10-30  29476  363 1
26  2020-11-03  29476  363 1
27  2020-11-04  29476  364 2
28  2020-11-08  29476  364 2
29  2020-11-13  29476  365 3
30  2020-11-15  29476  365 3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(newcolumn = week - min(week)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach with a join. You can create a reference table for the unique values, then assign the numeric index in order to finally join with the original dataframe. Here the code using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% 
  left_join(
    df %>% group_by(id,week) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% select(-N) %>%
      ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(Newweek=row_number())
  )
```

Output (Due to space only showed first 30 rows):

```
          date     id week Newweek
1   2020-11-05  11368  928       1
2   2020-11-12  13543 1040       1
3   2020-11-15  13543 1041       2
4   2020-11-16  13543 1041       2
5   2020-11-08  13798  506       1
6   2020-11-11  13798  506       1
7   2020-11-16  13798  506       1
8   2020-10-31  22657  356       1
9   2020-11-03  22657  356       1
10  2020-11-04  22657  357       2
11  2020-11-06  22657  357       2
12  2020-11-08  22657  357       2
13  2020-11-09  22657  357       2
14  2020-11-10  22657  357       2
15  2020-11-13  22657  358       3
16  2020-11-14  22657  358       3
17  2020-11-06  28666  140       1
18  2020-11-09  28666  140       1
19  2020-11-03  28738  701       1
20  2020-10-31  29392  652       1
21  2020-11-01  29392  652       1
22  2020-11-08  29392  653       2
23  2020-11-13  29392  653       2
24  2020-10-28  29476  363       1
25  2020-10-30  29476  363       1
26  2020-11-03  29476  363       1
27  2020-11-04  29476  364       2
28  2020-11-08  29476  364       2
29  2020-11-13  29476  365       3
30  2020-11-15  29476  365       3
```

Comment: Duck just to make sure - has your solution any advantage over @omri-newett solution? They both work and seem to give the same results. I can't accept both answers and before I do so with the shorter one I'd like to ask you if I'm not missing anything. Thank you

Comment: @blazej It is up to you choose what you believe is right for you. This solution would be flexible if you want to add other kind of index to identify your dates such as Week1,...,Weekn. That is how look up tables work :)